# Ruby: How to set a default value for nil keys on a hash created via hash literal notation?

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

In a free Ruby course I'm working through, I was shown the way to create a default value for a hash via constructor. And it looks like so:

```
no_nil_hash = Hash.new("default value for nil key")
puts no_nil_hash["non_existing_key"]
```

Which prints: `default value for nil key`

How would I go about this via the way of hash literal notation?

Did not find any answers via google and here are my futile attempts so far:

1. `via_hash_literal = {"default value for nil key"}` but this is causing an error: `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>`
2. `via_hash_literal = {=> "default value for nil key"}` causing more errors:
   `syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'` `via_hash_literal = { => "default value for nil key"}` `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input` `...=> "default value for nil key"}`
3. `via_hash_literal = {nil => "default value for nil key"}` does not throw an error but then `puts via_hash_literal["non_existing_key"]` does not print the default key: `default value for nil key`, instead I get an empty row of line.

Comment: Regarding _"nil keys"_ – you should distinguish between "nil" and "missing". It's perfectly fine for a hash to have `nil` as a key e.g. `h1 = { nil => 123 }` and also as a value e.g. `h2 = { foo: nil }`. Neither `h1[nil]` nor `h2[:foo]` would trigger the default value. Only a _missing_ key would do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{}` syntax to generate a new hash in Ruby doesn't support setting a default. But you can use [`Hash#default=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D) to set an default too:

```
hash = {}
hash.default = "default value"

hash[:foo]
#=> "default value"
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be written as the following:

```rb
no_nil_hash = {}
no_nil_hash.default = "default value for nil key"
puts no_nil_hash["non_existing_key"]
```

Result in IRB:

```
irb(main):001:0> no_nil_hash = {}
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> no_nil_hash.default = "default value for nil key"
=> "default value for nil key"
irb(main):003:0> no_nil_hash["non_existing_key"]
=> "default value for nil key"
```

Read more: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html